# How to fix pagination link to page 2 wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

Hi all I am a new of wordpress I have problame with pagination, I used plugin Wp-pagnavi ,When I click link to page 2 it same as page 1,How to to fix it.

You can see it at
http://westecmedia.com/?page_id=758

And this my code in page-event.php

```
<?php
/*
 *  Template Name: Page - Events Page
 */
?>
<?php get_header(); ?>
<div id="content-events">
    <div id="head-event"><h3>EVENTS</h3></div>
    <div id="main-event">

                <?php query_posts('category_name='.get_the_title().'&post_status=publish,future');?>

                <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div id="part-event">
                            <div id="entry-thumbnail">
                                    <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>

                            </div>
                            <div id="event-dess">
                            <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>
                                <p>
                                    <?php 
                                    $content = get_the_content();
                                    $content = strip_tags($content);
                                    echo substr($content, 0, 300);
                                    ?>
                                </p>
                                <div id="read-more"><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Read More</a></div>
                            </div>

                    </div>
                    <div id="line-bottom"></div>
                <?php endwhile; endif; ?>

                    <?php wp_pagenavi(); ?>

                    <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Help me please :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Include paged, documentation: https://codex.wordpress.org/Pagination

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'cat' => '5',
    'post_type' => 'post',
    'posts_per_page' => 6,
    'paged' => ( get_query_var('paged') ? get_query_var('paged') : 1),
);
query_posts($args);
while (have_posts()) : the_post();
 /* Do whatever you want to do for every page... */
endwhile;
wp_pagenavi();
wp_reset_query();  // Restore global post data
?>
```

Also don't use query_posts to fetch data in WordPress, consider using https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query.

Please ask WordPress related question here: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

I hope this helps.

Comment: Wow brother it is very work for me very veyr thank q brother,

Comment: Glad to know buddy :-)

Comment: Very very thank q brother, I have ask this question in stackflow 3 time about pagination wordpress